# Hibernate filter does not apply for join entity

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee-8, hibernate-filters

I am trying to understand hibernate filters, i thought that the filter is applied even if the query is not started from the filtered entity and can be applied if i just join to it.

My entities:

```
@Table(name = "SPM_SECTION", schema = "TEST")
@GenericGenerator(name = "MODSEC_ID.GEN", strategy = "uuid2")
public class ModuleSection implements Serializable {

private AcademicClass academicClass;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLASS_ID")
    public AcademicClass getAcademicClass() {
        return academicClass;
    }

    public void setAcademicClass(AcademicClass academicClass) {
        this.academicClass = academicClass;
    }
    
}

@Entity
@GenericGenerator(name = "AC_CLASS_ID.GEN", strategy = "uuid2")
@Where(clause="1=1")
@FilterDef(name= Resources.SECURITY_FILTER_NAME, parameters={@ParamDef(name=Resources.SECURITY_FILTER_PARAMETER, type="string")})
@Filter(name=Resources.SECURITY_FILTER_NAME, condition = "DISCRIMINATOR_ID in (:"+Resources.SECURITY_FILTER_PARAMETER+")")
@Table(name = "ACADEMIC_CLASS", schema = "TEST", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"OUS_ID", "YEAR_ID",
        "PERIOD_ID", "SHIFT_ID", "SEMESTER", "CODE" }))
public class AcademicClass implements java.io.Serializable {

    //I tried by having the association here, i also tried without it.
    private Set<ModuleSection> sections = new HashSet<>(0);
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "academicClass")
    public Set<ModuleSection> getSections() {
        return this.sections;
    }

    public void setSections(Set<ModuleSection> sections) {
        this.sections = sections;
    }

}
```

The filter is enabled through an interceptor and the parameter list is fetched from the database for security.

When i execute a query like this:

```
em.createQuery("select acc from AcademicClass acc ...........", AcademicClass.class)
.getResultList();
```

the filter is applied. But i also want the filter to be applied when my query starts from ModuleSection:

```
em.createQuery("select ms from ModuleSection ms join ms.academicClass acc", AcademicClass.class)
.getResultList();
```

In above query the filter is not applied.

The academicClass in ModuleSection entity is nullable but i also have other entities not null where the above case does not work.

I also tried to apply the @Filter or @FilterJoinTable in module section property with no luck:

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLASS_ID")
    @Filter(name=Resources.SECURITY_FILTER_NAME, condition = "DISCRIMINATOR_ID in (:"+Resources.SECURITY_FILTER_PARAMETER+")")
    @FilterJoinTable(name=Resources.SECURITY_FILTER_NAME, condition = "DISCRIMINATOR_ID in (:"+Resources.SECURITY_FILTER_PARAMETER+")")
    public AcademicClass getAcademicClass() {
        return academicClass;
    }
```

My questions:
Are filters meant to filter only the entity in the from clause? does the filter apply in join entities?
If I want to implement the above should I also add a DISCRIMINATOR_ID in ModuleSection and add the filter to that entity starting the query from there?

Comment: Why do you manually join `academicClass`?

Comment: It is a big query where i need filter to take place if I join with a filtered entity. Above is just an example.

Comment: I assume Hibernate needs to use its own mechanism to detect and apply filters and if you create a query manually you don't use the Hibernate mechanism to build the joins so they can't be filtered.

Comment: So the filter is applied only when i have the entity to the from clause not in joins? Because when the entity is in the from clause the filter is applied correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a silence about it in the hibernate documentation, but it looks like this is true that `@Filter` is applied only to the `from` clause.

Assuming that we have the following mapping:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACADEMIC_CLASS")
@FilterDef(
   name="isAccessible",
   parameters = @ParamDef(
      name="sec",
      type="string"
   )
)
@Filter(
   name="isAccessible",
   condition="{acClass}.discriminator_id in (:sec)",
   aliases = {
      @SqlFragmentAlias(alias = "acClass", table= "TEST_SCHEMA.ACADEMIC_CLASS")
   }
)
public class AcademicClass
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "class_id")
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "academicClass")
   private Set<ModuleSection> sections;

   // getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "SPM_SECTION")
public class ModuleSection
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "sec_id")
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "sec_class_id")
   private AcademicClass academicClass;

   // getters/setters
}
```

When we run the following query:

```java
session
   .enableFilter("isAccessible")
   .setParameter("sec", "A1");

List<AcademicClass> classes = session.createQuery(
    "select ac from ModuleSection ms join ms.academicClass ac",
    AcademicClass.class
).getResultList();
```

The filter is not applied. It should happen in the [JoinSequence.toJoinFragment](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/internal/JoinSequence.java#L223). The `filterCondition` is empty in this case.

But for the rewritten in the following way query:

```java
List<AcademicClass> classes = session.createQuery(
    "select ac from ModuleSection ms, AcademicClass ac where ms.academicClass = ac",
    AcademicClass.class
).getResultList();
```

We will have:

[image]

and as result the following query will be generated:

```sql
Hibernate: 
/* select
     ac 
   from
      ModuleSection ms,
      AcademicClass ac 
   where
        ms.academicClass = ac
*/
select
   academiccl1_.class_id as class_id1_0_ 
from TEST_SCHEMA.SPM_SECTION modulesect0_ cross 
join TEST_SCHEMA.ACADEMIC_CLASS academiccl1_ 
where academiccl1_.discriminator_id in (?) 
  and modulesect0_.sec_class_id=academiccl1_.class_id
```

So, as a workaround you can rewrite your query in this way.

The `@FilterJoinTable` [annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter-join-table) can be used only if you have a *link table* between the parent entity and the child table.